# MySQL python connector returns empty result on select query

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to fetch a result from my database table users, using the cursor.execute() statement but when I try to execute the program, I get an empty result.
Here's the code

**import mysql.connector as mysql;
mycon=mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="12345",database="Markwiss")
cursor =mycon.cursor()
cursor.execute("select*from users;")**

I recently updated both python and mysql to the latest versions and since then I have been facing this problem. I have tried executing some other statements like INSERT INTO, DELETE FROM, and they have been working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're executing the query but not reading it.
Try adding the following:

`result = cursor.fetchall()`

then you can access each line of the query with a for loop:

````
for line in result:
        #do something ```
````

Comment: thanks for help, mate:) I was going crazy about what I did wrong.

Comment: No problem. If it worked, please don't forget to mark my answer as the right one